# Docker: Error pulling image, executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker

I'm trying to pull some image, and have strange error:

```
sudo docker pull wnameless/oracle-xe-11g  
Pulling repository wnameless/oracle-xe-11g
f8d224b82290: Error pulling image (latest) from wnameless/oracle-xe-11g, Untar exit status 1 exec: "xz": executable file not found in $PATH found in $PATH ror downloading dependent layers 
2014/11/28 23:08:26 Error pulling image (latest) from wnameless/oracle-xe-11g, Untar exit status 1 exec: "xz": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Strange, but Ubuntu image works fine

```
sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu
```

System version:
Linux Mint 17 Qiana
Kernel version 3.13.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As result, this problem was only in latest version of Docker (lxc-docker package, version > 1.3.x). I have removed this package, and install docker.io package (v. 1.0.1). Now everything is fine.

Answer (score 2):

[Issue 9327](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9327) was introduced in 1.3.2 and should be fixed in 1.4.0, so 1.3.1 should be fine (beside lack of security fixes which caused this regression). If you creating images with mkimage.sh in 1.3.2 next fix will help:

```
$ > git diff
diff --git a/contrib/mkimage.sh b/contrib/mkimage.sh
index cd2fa74..fda16ab 100755
--- a/contrib/mkimage.sh
+++ b/contrib/mkimage.sh
@@ -71,7 +71,7 @@ nameserver 8.8.8.8
 nameserver 8.8.4.4
 EOF

-tarFile="$dir/rootfs.tar.xz"
+tarFile="$dir/rootfs.tar.bz2"
 touch "$tarFile"

 (
@@ -82,7 +82,7 @@ touch "$tarFile"
 echo >&2 "+ cat > '$dir/Dockerfile'"
 cat > "$dir/Dockerfile" <<'EOF'
 FROM scratch
-ADD rootfs.tar.xz /
+ADD rootfs.tar.bz2 /
 EOF

 # if our generated image has a decent shell, let's set a default command
```